# 403 status code while trying to access webpage from Python

Tags: php, python, ajax

I've already tried using JSON but can't really read this page.

This is my python code. I've tried it on other websites and it works, but on this website it returns a 403.

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request('http://www.taringa.net/envivo/ajax.php')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

print the_page
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the 'User-Agent' header in order to make this work.

Urllib code:

```
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.taringa.net/envivo/ajax.php')
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla')
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print resp.code  # Gives 200.
print resp.read()  # Gives the HTML of the page.
```

I would recommend that you use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) mainly because it makes this kind of stuff very easy.

Requests code:

```
h = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla'}
requests.get('http://www.taringa.net/envivo/ajax.php', headers=h)
```

Comment: sos un capo!!! thanks a lot troesma, lince macho alfa intergalactico de las praderas africanas!

Answer (score 1):

Better use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). I tried your script and got the status of 403. This means that access to it is closed, for whatever reason, I do not know.

Comment: it's what i was thinking... but i have to install the library in win7 python and im thinking how to do it... but thanks i'll try... the xtrange thing is that if u enter to the page u can see all the ajax responses

Comment: on windows install pip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: i have installed pip and package now says 403 forbiden... this is the scriptimport requests

    r = requests.get('http://www.taringa.net/envivo/ajax.php', stream=True)

for line in r.iter_lines():
    if line: print line

Comment: Library will not solve your problems. It will only help to write the code easier. Why returns 403 status, I do not know. Perhaps you need to put some cookies and headers ...